# Sign in with Apple in realm SwiftUI exception: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: swift, swiftui, realm, realm-mobile-platform, nsexception

I am trying to implement sign in with apple to Realm.
I already did the configuration from the docs: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/app-services/authentication/apple/#std-label-apple-id-authentication

Now I am trying to add the sign in with Apple button and the flow.

The login button on SwiftUI:

```swift
SignInWithAppleButton(.signIn, onRequest: { request in
    isLoggingIn = true
    request.requestedScopes = [.email]
}, onCompletion: { result in
    switch result {
    case .success(let authResults):
        guard let credentials = authResults.credential as? ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential,
              let identityToken = credentials.identityToken,
              let identityTokenString = String(data: identityToken, encoding: .utf8) else { return }
        
        repo.loginwithApple(appleTokenIDString: identityTokenString) { user, error in
            
        }
    case .failure(let error):
        isLoggingIn = false
    }
})
```

`repo.loginwithApple` calls the method from the shared kotlin repository:

```kotlin
suspend fun loginwithApple(appleTokenIDString: String): User {
    var credentials = Credentials.apple(idToken = appleTokenIDString)

    return appService.login(credentials = credentials)
}
```

Whenever I try to do the login with the apple sign in button I get this exception:

```
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SharedRealmRepo loginwithAppleAppleTokenIDString:completionHandler:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x281fe4960'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Any idea why the exception happens?

Comment: Can I suggest just trying to login with the code presented in the Getting Started Guide [Apple Login](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/users/authenticate-users/#apple-user) and see if that works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like removing the Output Files from XCode will solve the issue, but I do not know why.

[image]

Maybe someone has a explanation of why this happens. The output files will not let the realm repo re-build?

Comment: This fixed the issue!
@Diego Freniche, do you know how this can affect?
I think that the repo is not rebuild on the xcode because of the output files..

Comment: As this is a external library most probably Xcode wasn't building it and using the cached version. Cleaning caches always help!

Answer (score 2):

The error `unrecognized selector sent to instance` means that the object `repo` does not have that method, that is, `loginwithApple`, with that signature, is not in your Kotlin code. This happens most probably because:

- the method is not there at all (doesn't seem to be your problem here, but always double check, save all Kotlin files, regenerate the library and copy it again in your iOS project to be 100% sure you have a fresh copy). You can always check is a symbol is in a library using `strings` from the command line.
- the method is there, but parameters are different. In this case Swift expects `loginwithApple` to receive both a String and a closure, and this closure to take user, error. In your Kotlin code I don't see that closure, although my Kotlin is not good.
- method is there, parameters match, but is not `public`

I'd say is #2

Comment: I am using xcode for the swiftui and android studio for the repository.
Whenever I do a change in the android repo, and runt it on xcode, shouldnt that change to be present? Do I need to re-run the shared module on the android studio as well?

Comment: or rebuild it on android studio?

Comment: Not an expert on KMM, also don't know if you have some script to automate this in place, but try to save, build on Android Studio, re-install that library in Xcode using the method you're using right now (can be just a simple copy), then try again. I'll also double-check if the method is public and if it gets a closure.

Comment: the solution of this solved the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75790141/identical-methods-in-realm-exception-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance/75794135?noredirect=1#comment133700638_75794135

Comment: do you know why the output files was the issue?