# Identical methods in realm exception: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: swift, swiftui, realm, kotlin-multiplatform, realm-mobile-platform

I have a kmm app. In swiftUI I call the login method from the Kotlin repo:

```
 repo.login(email: $userId.wrappedValue, password: $password.wrappedValue) { user, error in
      }
```

I have 2 methods that login identically on my Realm repository.

```
suspend fun login(email: String, password: String): User {
        return appService.login(Credentials.emailPassword(email, password))
    }
suspend fun dologin(email: String, password: String): User {
        return appService.login(Credentials.emailPassword(email, password))
    }
```

But just the first login works: `repo.login`

Whenever I try to use the second login: `repo.dologin`, it will show the exception:

```
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SharedRealmRepo dologinEmail:password:completionHandler:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x281fe4960'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Why this happens? Do I need to recompile the shared module in some way?

Comment: The question is a little vague. We don't know what `dologin` does or what it's expecting. It seems a `SharedRealmRepo` is involved which appears to be a third party library (??). SO is probably not the best place to troubleshoot third party libraries though - I would check with the developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like removing the Output Files from XCode will solve the issue, but I do not know why.

[image]

Maybe someone has a explanation of why this happens.
The output files will not let the realm repo re-build?

Comment: This solved the issue! Do you know why this happens? @Jay

Comment: @dhaval123 Perhaps the repo included some (incompatible) already built data or maybe the repo is pointing to something within a file structure that doesn't exist within yours? It's hard to know without digging into the original repo itself